# Return List of Objects from Spring Batch Custom ItemReader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, vtd-xml

I have a requirement to process thousands of Payments..So I used VtdXml instead of StaxEventItemReader in Spring Batch, I have created Custom Item Reader for the same. In order to read huge xml with Multi Threading, I have created partition with 10 Threads. I am splitting huge xml file into 10 files and assigning to each Thread in Partition. Once I read the xml and I will convert into list of Objects and send to Writer. After received in  Writer, I will customize the List of Objects and Merge into the final List. Whenever Am returning list of Objects read called again and it is never ending. How do I pass the list of Objects to the Writer and merge into the final List?

```
public class VtdWholeItemReader<T> implements ResourceAwareItemReaderItemStream<T> {


private Resource resource;

private boolean noInput;

private boolean strict = true;

private InputStream inputStream;

private int index = 0;





@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) {
    Assert.notNull(resource, "The Resource must not be null.");

    noInput = true;
    if (!resource.exists()) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Input resource must exist (reader is in 'strict' mode)");
        }
        log.warn("Input resource does not exist " + resource.getDescription());
        return;
    }
    if (!resource.isReadable()) {
        if (strict) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Input resource must be readable (reader is in 'strict' mode)");
        }
        log.warn("Input resource is not readable " + resource.getDescription());
        return;
    }
    noInput = false;
}

@Override
public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) {

}

@Override
public void close() {
    try {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        inputStream = null;
    }

}

@Override
public void setResource(Resource resource) {
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public T read()
        throws java.lang.Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    if (noInput) {
        return null;
    }
    List<Payment> paymentList = new ArrayList<Payment>();

    try {
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        VTDGen vgHen = new VTDGen();
        boolean headercheck = true;
        if (vg.parseFile("src/main/resources/input/partitioner/" + resource.getFilename(), false)) {

            VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
            AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
            ap.selectXPath("/root/Payment");
            // flb contains all the offset and length of the segments to be skipped
            FastLongBuffer flb = new FastLongBuffer(4);
            int i;
            byte[] xml = vn.getXML().getBytes();
            while ((i = ap.evalXPath()) != -1) {
                flb.append(vn.getElementFragment());
            }
            int size = flb.size();
            log.info("Payment Size {}", size);
            if (size != 0) {
                for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                    String message = new String(xml, flb.lower32At(k), flb.upper32At(k), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

                    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

                    Payment payment = objectMapper
                            .readValue(message, Payment.class);
                    paymentList.add(pcPayment);
                    index = pcPaymentList.size() + 1;

                }
            }
            log.info("Payment List:: {}", paymentList.size());
            log.info("Index::{}", index);
            return index > paymentList .size() ? null : (T) paymentList;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

}
```

**SpringBatch ConfigClass**

```
private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBatchConfig.class);

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
ResourcePatternResolver resoursePatternResolver;


@Bean
public Job job() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").start(readpayment()).build();
}

@Bean
public JobLauncher jobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository() throws Exception {
    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setTransactionManager(new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
    return (JobRepository) factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
protected Step readpayment() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("readpayment").partitioner("paymentStep", partitioner(null))
            .step(paymentStep()).taskExecutor(taskExecutor()).build();
}

@Bean
protected Step paymentStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("paymentStep")
            .<Payment,Payment>chunk(10)
         .reader(xmlFileItemReader(null))
        .writer(writer()).build();
}


@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(10);
    taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
ItemReader<Payment> xmlFileItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}") String filename) {
    VtdWholeItemReader<Payment> xmlFileReader = new VtdWholeItemReader<>();
    xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("input/partitioner/" + filename));
    return xmlFileReader;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public CustomMultiResourcePartitioner partitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['fileName']}") String fileName) {
    logger.info("fileName {}", fileName);
    CustomMultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new CustomMultiResourcePartitioner();
    Resource[] resources;
    try {
        resources = resoursePatternResolver.getResources("file:src/main/resources/input/partitioner/*.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I/O problems when resolving the input file pattern.", e);
    }
    partitioner.setResources(resources);
    return partitioner;
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Payment> writer() {
    return new PaymentItemWriter();
}
```

**PaymentItemWriter**

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends List<Payment>> items) throws Exception {

    log.info("Items {}", items.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try making ItemWriter bean as step scope ["@StepScope"] in Spring batch configuration class

Answer (score 0):

Make your `xmlFileItemReader` method return the actual type `VtdWholeItemReader` instead of the interface type `ItemReader`:

```
@Bean
@StepScope
VtdWholeItemReader<Payment> xmlFileItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext[fileName]}") String filename) {
   VtdWholeItemReader<Payment> xmlFileReader = new VtdWholeItemReader<>();
   xmlFileReader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("input/partitioner/" + filename));
   return xmlFileReader;
}
```

This way, Spring will correctly proxy your reader as an `ItemStreamReader` (and not `ItemReader`) and honor the contract of calling `open/update/close` methods.

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, Thanks for Suggestion, Now open, update and close methods are calling in VtdWholeItemReader, Now Still am not able to receive list of Objects which am returning to Writer Class. If am Returning null, Spring batch Job gets completed, If am Returning list..Reader method never ending.

Comment: You need to make sure your reader returns `null` at some point to signal that the data source is exhausted.

Comment: If am returning list, Still itemWriter is not calling.. Kindly help me to create vtd based spring batch xml reader.